# How to load an XmlDocument without changing Encoding

Tags: c#, xml

Im trying to save a XML file through an XmlDocument instance,  but then the content is loaded, the doc object seems to change the original content and translate it with encoding.

Content to Load into XmlDocument:

```
        <CAF version="1.0">
            <DA>
                <RS>SOCIEDAD FARMACEUTICA O&apos;HIGGINS SPA</RS>
                <RSAPK>
                    <M>yT67262Z6tQHk.....PIG0CfCFz7b/MNaQ==</M>
                    <E>Aw==</E>
                </RSAPK>
            </DA>
            <FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">oWjU2fGhJ5PwjpQwCDMk.....oL//dMLnhPt7GQ==</FRMA>
        </CAF>
```

Algorithm applied:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        doc.LoadXml(content);   // <--here doc takes a "translated" XML content with encoding 

        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
        signedXml.SigningKey = certificado.PrivateKey;
        Signature XMLSignature = signedXml.Signature;
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "#" + referenceID;

        XmlDsigC14NTransform t = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(t);

        XMLSignature.SignedInfo.AddReference(reference);
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        keyInfo.AddClause(new RSAKeyValue((RSA)certificado.PrivateKey));
        keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificado));
        XMLSignature.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
        doc.Save(pathResult);
```

When doc object is loaded with content, it takes this inner and outer XML:

```
        <CAF version="1.0">
            <DA>
                <RS>SOCIEDAD FARMACEUTICA O'HIGGINS SPA</RS>
                <RSAPK>
                    <M>yT67262Z6tQHk.....PIG0CfCFz7b/MNaQ==</M>
                    <E>Aw==</E>
                </RSAPK>
            </DA>
            <FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">oWjU2fGhJ5PwjpQwCDMk.....oL//dMLnhPt7GQ==</FRMA>
        </CAF>
```

This produces an invalid sign, because original content has `&apos;` and not `'`

Comment: Note that XML signing should do normalization of XML so I seriously doubt that `&apos;` vs. `'` would make difference for signing... Whitespace handling on other hand... (Indeed this comment is totally unrelated to the question you are asking...)

Comment: The problem should be fixed by the people who generated the xml.  Youy code is doing what it is suppose to do.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but when the doc is saved, the original content is changed, so the original sign remains invalid :|